# Python creating a dictionary from a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to create a data dictionary from a csv file and am having some trouble. I have successfully been able to make a dictionary from two lists in my program below is my code:

```
playerRank = [[tournamentResults[i],rankingPoints[8]] for i in range(0,len(tournamentResults))]
dict1 = dict(playerRank)
```

However, when I attempt to make a dictionary out of data I have in a csv file I get an error 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'list''. Below is the code I tried:

```
totalRank = []
with open("mycsvfile.csv") as players:
    for row in csv.reader(players):
        totalRank.append(row)
    totalRank = [[totalRank[i],0] for i in range(0,len(totalRank))]
dict2 = dict(totalRank)
```

I don't understand why the second attempt at making a dictionary is throwing back the error whereas, the first dictionary is fine? Any help on how I could resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why use a list comprehension that creates a list of pairs just to pass it to `dict`, when you can use a dict comprehension instead? `dict1 = {tournamentResults[i]: rankingPoints[8] for i in range(0, len(tournamentResults))}` Or, more simply, `dict1 = {result: rankingPoints[8] for result in tournamentResults}`

Comment: Maybe totalRank[i] is a list, check the type of the `row`. The reason for the error is that a `list` is not hashable. For a dictionary, it consisted of keys and values, and the key needs to be a hashable type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, as the error message says, lists are not hashable, which means you can't use them as dict keys.

In fact, the *reason* lists aren't hashable is to *prevent* you from using them as dict keys. Lists are mutable, and if you mutate a key in a dict, lookup won't work anymore. (Technically, you could get around this by using a hash function based on object identity, instead of the contained values—but then either `==` wouldn't be useful, or it wouldn't line up with `hash`.)

The usual solution is pretty simple: a tuple is just like a dict, except immutable. So if your keys are lists, instead of this:

```
[[key, value] for ...]
```

… you do this:

```
[[tuple(key), value] for ...]
```

And now, you can pass it to `dict` and everything works.

Of course this assumes that you don't *want* to mutate those sequences after creating them.

---

Meanwhile, I'm not sure why you want to use a sequence of values in the first place here, and you may in fact want something simpler. Your `totalRank` is a list of *rows*, and you probably only want one *column* in each row, not the whole thing. In that case, just do this:

```
[[totalRank[0], 0] for ...]
```

Or, alternatively, instead of `totalRank.append(row)`, do `totalRank.append(row[0])`.

(I'm assuming it's the first column you want here; obviously you can do `row[3]` or whatever if you want a different one.)

---

While we're at it, if you're using Python 3, or Python 2.7, you can write this more readably (and efficiently, too) using a dictionary comprehension instead of a list comprehension. Instead of this:

```
lst = [[key, value] for ...]
dct = dict(lst)
```

… just do this:

```
dct = {key: value for ...}
```

Also you don't have to loop over `i in range(len(lst))` if the only thing you're using `i` for is `lst[i]`; just loop over `element in lst`.

Putting it all together:

```
dct2 = {tuple(rank): 0 for rank in totalRank}
```

… or, depending on what you wanted:

```
dct2 = {rank[0]: 0 for rank in totalRank}
```

---

And one more improvement. This:

```
totalRank = []
for row in csv.reader(players):
    totalRank.append(row)
```

Is just a verbose way of writing this:

```
totalRank = list(csv.reader(players))
```

Or, if you wanted just the first column:

```
totalRank = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(players))
```

So we can reduce your entire loop to this:

```
with open("mycsvfile.csv") as players:
    dict2 = {tuple(row): 0 for row in csv.reader(players)}
```

… or, again:

```
with open("mycsvfile.csv") as players:
    dict2 = {row[0]: 0 for row in csv.reader(players)}
```